# Octave crashes on matrix multiplication of dimension 52 by 52

Tags: octave

```
magic(5) * magic(5) // works 
magic(52) * magic(52) // fails 


panic: Illegal instruction -- stopping myself...
attempting to save variables to 'octave-core'...
save to 'octave-core' complete
```

I am on Ubuntu 13.04, 32 bit, linux kernel 3.8.0-31-generic

I tried uninstalling atlas as mentioned [here](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=607244) but could not find libatlas3gf-base so removed fgfs-atlas instead but that did not work.

Comment: Please provide us with the Octave version you're using and the method you followed to install it.

Comment: sorry, I don't have that information anymore. I have formatted my laptop

Comment: Anyways, the code should work without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Install the following packages first

```
libblas3gf
libblas-doc
libblas-dev

liblapack3gf
liblapack-doc
liblapack-dev
```

And if that does not work, search for 'blas linear' in your software package manager and install all except for Java,python,perl etc.

Ref: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1505249

Comment: I'm having the same problem on a Mac with Octave 4.0.2, installed from the GUI disk image. When I try "pkg install libblas3gf" it says the file does not exist. Do I need to download it from somewhere? For "blas linear", do I try to install that from within Octave or some external package manager?